# Is this a place to post a link to my desktop site and ask for feedback on the UX?

Tags: discussion

Is this a place to post a link to my desktop site and ask for feedback on the UX ?

Answer (score 3):

No, this isn't the place for site reviews. Stack Exchange sites are repositories for questions people have about a particular UX problem, and the solutions to those problems, so that when other people have those same questions they can come here and find an answer. Site reviews offer no such benefit to the community, only to the asker.